# Передача данных между PHP и Java

Tags: php, java

интересуют способы передачи данных между PHP и приложением написанным на Java. Если точнее то необходимо чтобы данные с сайта, передавались в работающее приложение. Насколько я понял, то можно использовать SOAP. Но мне хотелось бы узнать мнение более опытных людей, какой метод использовать. По сути мне необходимо передавать несколько int'ов и String'ов, из скрипта на PHP, и запускать процесс обработки этих данных в приложении. Само приложение получает данные, и выбирает один из n-ного количества серверов, который занимается обработкой.

Comment: как вы хотите использовать SOAP или другой протокол например IIOP?

Comment: Банальное решение отдавать json с какого нибудь urla API не подходит?

Comment: Если честно не задумывался над таким способом реализации, а можно узнать подробнее о данном способе? Возможно существуют примеры реализации такой связи между вебом и java

Comment: Я на php генерирую html страничку с json, а на java я его получаю и обрабатываю. В интернете есть куча примеров,  и java имеет класс для работы с json.

Comment: Использую XML т.к. используется статическая структура. Использовал пакетную передачу (работа с байт массивом), когда данные были динамическими и требовался хедлер для определения типа пакета и сложности вложения. Для вашей задачи подойдёт XML который с обоих сторон выльется в 10 строк кода. DOMDocument для PHP и DocumentBuilderFactory для Java.